Clarification on "each digit represents an increasing power of 10" in number representation
I'm trying to understand a statement I came across: "each digit represents an increasing power of 10." This seems unclear to me because, from my understanding, each digit itself does not represent an increasing power of 10. Instead, the position of each digit in a number corresponds to an increasing power of 10.
Am I right?
Source on Youtube Video (1:22 timing): https://youtu.be/Xpk67YzOn5w?si=id-TZM0PZHkWkFgp&t=81
For example, in the number 22706:
digits:  ----- |2|2|7|0|6|
positions:- |4|3|2|1|0|

Position of 6 is 0, so it's 6*10^0
Position of 0 is 1, so it's 0*10^1

Could someone clarify what is meant by "each digit represents an increasing power of 10"?

I think "position" in this statement is implied.

I think you are basically right; not having seen the video. Here it could mean something special, like not the exponents ... 6 5 4 3 2 1 0, but 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., not our right to left numbers. Though natural would be 2.10^4+2.10³+7.10²+0.10+6.

To me, those statements are equivalent. "The digit 7 (in that position) represents 700". How else do you think could this be interpreted?

@MarkRansom I understood, I thought about it, but I doubted it, so I tried to ask other people who understand the topic. I'm glad that my thoughts agree on this

@JoopEggen I'm not sure what you meant by your comment. I understand that first you need 610^0, then 010^1. then 710^2, then 210^3, and finally 2*10^4

@Bergi I wasn't sure, so I decided to ask you - more experienced comrades. I understand that 7 in position 2 represents 700, however the author would say something like "Each digit (7) represents an increasing power of 10", which didn't sound specific to me.
Again, I wasn't sure, so I wanted to check with those who are much more experienced in this than me

I have heard "digit" used in this sense before, i.e., the "one's digit", the "tens digits", the "hundreds digit" and so on. See also: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digit

@topsail best comment overall, you can create answer and I will approve it, sir. Next time, I will check wiki if I will have questions like that

The word digit may be used to refer to position in a sequence of values, often together with its place value, so you could for example speak of the ones
digit, the tens digit, the hundreds digit and so on. Presumably in a base 2 system you might instead refer to the ones digit, the twos digit, the fours digit and so on. I found this definition and example in a wiktionary link:

digit (mathematics): A position in a sequence of numerals representing
a place value in a positional number system.

Synonyms: place; figure (informal, usually in discussion of money)
Example Usage: The base-10 number 123.4 has four digits: the hundreds digit is 1, the tens digit is 2, the units digit is 3, and the tenths digit is 4.


Of course digit also has its other and probably more common meaning, which is a symbol used to represent the numbers in a positional number system, such as the digits 0,1,...9 in the base 10 system or the digits 0,1,...F in the base 16 system.
